# TypeTag for case classes

Tags: scala, reflection, case-class, scala-reflect, reify

I would like to make a case class `Bla` that takes a type parameter `A` and it knows the type of `A` at runtime (it stores it in its `info` field).

My attempt is shown in the example below. The problem is that this example does not compile.

```
case class Bla[A] (){
  val info=Run.paramInfo(this) // this does not compile
}
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Run extends App{
  val x=Bla[Int]
  def paramInfo[T](x:T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): String = {
    val targs = tag.tpe match { case TypeRef(_, _, args) => args }
    val tinfo=s"type of $x has type arguments $targs"
    println(tinfo)
    tinfo
  }
  paramInfo(x)
}
```

However when I comment `val info=Run.paramInfo(this)` then the program runs fine and prints:

> type of Bla() has type arguments List(Int)

Is there a way to make this example below compile ? (or in some other way achieve the same goal, i.e. that a case class is self aware of the type of it's type parameter?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass the implicit type tag parameter to the case class constructor (otherwise the type information is lost before calling `paraInfo` which requires it):

```
case class Bla[A : TypeTag]() { ... }
```

Which is shorthand for:

```
case class Bla[A](implicit tag: TypeTag[A]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

There's little point in using reflection based APIs for this, shapeless has a typeclass that exposes compile time information to runtime using an implicit macro.

```
import shapeless.Typeable


class Test[T : Typeable] {
  def info: String = implicitly[Typeable[T]].describe
}
```

It's also relatively easy to roll your own thing here, with the added inconvenience of having to compile the implicit macro in a different compilation unit than whatever is using it.

Comment: Thanks, isn't the value of `info` determined at compile time when using `TypeTag` ?

Comment: @jhegedus Nope, `TypeTag` is a reflection API thing, it's a more evolved version of java's `Class[_]`.

Comment: It seems like that the value of TypeTag is decided at compile time: "Like scala.reflect.Manifest, TypeTags can be thought of as objects which carry along all type information available at compile time, to runtime. For example, TypeTag[T] encapsulates the runtime type representation of some compile-time type T. Note however, that TypeTags should be considered to be a richer replacement of the pre-2.10 notion of a Manifest, that are additionally fully integrated with Scala reflection." http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html